# Get subdomain and load it to url with greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, url, greasemonkey

I am having the URL http://somesubdomain.domain.com (subdomains may vary, domain is always  the same). Need to take subdomain and reload the page with something like domain.com/some/path/here/somesubdomain using greasemonkey (or open a new window with URL domain.com/some/path/here/somesubdomain, whatever).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
var full = window.location.host
//window.location.host is subdomain.domain.com
var parts = full.split('.')
var sub = parts[0]
var domain = parts[1]
var type = parts[2]
//sub is 'subdomain', 'domain', type is 'com'
var newUrl = 'http://' + domain + '.' + type + '/your/other/path/' + subDomain
window.open(newUrl);
```

Comment: What if the domain is google.co.uk? This will return the wrong subdomain.

Comment: To get only subdomain: window.location.host.split('.')[0];

Comment: @TLK is right, and Philip's solution only works if the subdomain always contains no dots. Sometimes subdomains have dots in them, making sub-subdomains, etc. I've provided a more complete (and much more painful, sadly) solution below.

Comment: @TLK Yep, and if domain is "sub1.sub2.domain.com" it will be also wrong

Answer (score 26):

The answer provided by Derek will work in the most common cases, but will not work for "xxx.xxx" sub domains, or "host.co.uk". (also, using window.location.host, will also retrieve the port number, which is not treated : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_host.asp)

To be honest I do not see a perfect solution for this problem.
Personally, I've created a method for host name splitting which I use very often because it covers a larger number of host names.

This method splits the hostname into `{domain: "", type: "", subdomain: ""}`

```
function splitHostname() {
        var result = {};
        var regexParse = new RegExp('([a-z\-0-9]{2,63})\.([a-z\.]{2,5})$');
        var urlParts = regexParse.exec(window.location.hostname);
        result.domain = urlParts[1];
        result.type = urlParts[2];
        result.subdomain = window.location.hostname.replace(result.domain + '.' + result.type, '').slice(0, -1);;
        return result;
}

console.log(splitHostname());
```

This method only returns the subdomain as a string:

```
function getSubdomain(hostname) {
        var regexParse = new RegExp('[a-z\-0-9]{2,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,5}$');
        var urlParts = regexParse.exec(hostname);
        return hostname.replace(urlParts[0],'').slice(0, -1);
}

console.log(getSubdomain(window.location.hostname));
// for use in node with express:  getSubdomain(req.hostname)
```

These two methods will work for most common domains (including co.uk)
**NOTE**: the `slice` at the end of sub domains is to remove the extra dot.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I used the Dereks solution and got into trouble when I suddenly didn't have a subdomain. Vlads answer works better in my case.

Comment: The 100% exact answer is the answer of jlbang on this page.
Filip's anwser is smaller footprint, but pretty incomplete.
However, a small footprint, though more complete one is given by sidanmor here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752963/get-domain-name-without-subdomains-using-javascript

Answer (score 4):

The solutions provided here work some of the time, or even most of the time, but not everywhere. To the best of my knowledge, the best way to find the full subdomain of *any* domain (and remember, sometimes subdomains have periods in them too! You can have sub-subdomains, etc) is to use the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/), which is maintained by Mozilla.

The part of the URL that isn't in the Public Suffix List is the subdomain plus the domain itself, joined by a dot. Once you remove the public suffix, you can remove the domain and have just the subdomain left by removing the last segment between the dots.

Let's look at a complicated example. Say you're testing `sub.sub.example.pvt.k12.ma.us`. `pvt.k12.ma.us` is a public suffix, believe it or not! So if you used the Public Suffix List, you'd be able to quickly turn that into `sub.sub.example` by removing the known suffix. Then you could go from `sub.sub.example` to just `sub.sub` after stripping off the last portion of the remaining pieces, which was the domain. `sub.sub` is your subdomain.

Comment: The only drawback of using this list is it requires Mozilla to discover the domains and curate their list. It could be used as a first pass in an algorithm that then resorts to one of the other more naive methods if no match is found.

Comment: @crush, I agree, that's a problem. However, given that the list is used in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Internet Explorer (as explained on [the Learn page of that site](https://publicsuffix.org/learn/)) I'm pretty confident it is maintained pretty well. At worst, a very odd edge case could temporarily fall through.

Comment: Interesting resource! Any idea if this list will be updated with the new GTLDs as well? Also, did not know the process is so arbitrary - any registrar can choose to delegate any tld as top level.

Answer (score 0):

This could work in most cases except for the one that @jlbang mention

```js
const split=location.host.split(".");
let subdomain="";
let domain="";
if(split.length==1){//localHost
  domain=split[0];
}else if(split.length==2){//sub.localHost or example.com
  if(split[1].includes("localhost")){//sub.localHost
    domain=split[1];
    subdomain=split[0];
  }else{//example.com
    domain=split.join(".");
  }
}else{//sub2.sub.localHost or sub2.sub.example.com or sub.example.com or example.com.ec sub.example.com.ec or  ... etc
  const last=split[split.length-1];
  const lastLast=split[split.length-2];
  if(last.includes("localhost")){//sub2.sub.localHost
    domain=last;
    subdomain=split.slice(0,split.length-1).join(".");
  }else if(last.length==2 && lastLast.length<=3){//example.com.ec or sub.example.com.ec
    domain=split.slice(split.length-3,split.length).join(".");
    if(split.length>3){//sub.example.com.ec
      subdomain=split.slice(0,split.length-3).join(".");
    }
  }else{//sub2.sub.example.com
    domain=split.slice(split.length-2,split.length).join(".");
    subdomain=split.slice(0,split.length-2).join(".");
  }
}
const newUrl = 'http://example.com/some/path/here/' + subdomain
```

Answer (score 0):

I adapted Vlad's solution in modern Typescript:

```
const splitHostname = (
    hostname: string
  ): { domain: string; type: string; subdomain: string } | undefined => {
    var urlParts = /([a-z-0-9]{2,63}).([a-z.]{2,5})$/.exec(hostname);
    if (!urlParts) return;
    const [, domain, type] = urlParts;
    const subdomain = hostname.replace(`${domain}.${type}`, "").slice(0, -1);
    return {
      domain,
      type,
      subdomain,
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

get a subdomain from URL

```
function getSubdomain(url) {
url = url.replace( "https://www.","");
url = url.replace( "http://www.","");
url = url.replace( "https://","");
url = url.replace("http://", "");
var temp = url.split("/");
if (temp.length > 0) {
    var temp2 = temp[0].split(".");
    if (temp2.length > 2) {
        return temp2[0];
    }
    else {
        return "";
    }
}
return "";
```

}