# Get domain name without subdomains using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to get the domain name without subdomains?

e.g. if the url is "http://one.two.roothost.co.uk/page.html" how to get "roothost.co.uk"?

Comment: That’s not what you would call the [canonical name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record).

Comment: @Gumbo http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CanonicalHostNames

Comment: Just to clarify, by "canonical hostname" you mean that "one.two.roothost.co.uk" redirects to "roothost.co.uk," as described in the link above, correct?

Comment: now you're going to have to define "root host name" for us

Comment: by root host name i mean the registered domain name. the root host with all the sub domains removed as i described in the question. i.e. one.two.roothost.co.uk => roothost.co.uk

Comment: So if I host my site at bobsfreehost.com, and Bob gives me the subdomain "mystuff," do you want mystuff.bobsfreehost.com, or bobsfreehost.com? See where I'm going with this?

Comment: I think I've now made the question as clear as i can make it. Don't concern yourself with where Bob is hosting his website. No matter where it's hosted. I need a sure way of finding the A Record host name of a given url.

Comment: Have a look at this question and answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript

Comment: I added the bounty as I'd like to know the host without the subdomains, the question you linked to doesn't help with that.

Comment: @XO - I posted an answer below with working JSFiddle link. Can you please confirm if it helps you ?

Comment: So far the only answer I can see that's "correct" would be the one @MaximillianLaumeister posted but I can't accept the bounty for another 21 hours so I'll wait till then and see if anyone else comes up with anything. Personally I'm looking for a way to get ANY domain without the subdomain, your answer looks like it only works for some types of domains and doesn't use a proven library or method to get the result unlike his.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Following is a solution to extract a domain name without any subdomains. This solution doesn't make any assumptions about the URL format, so it should work for any URL. Since some domain names have one suffix (`.com`), and some have two or more (`.co.uk`), to get an accurate result in all cases, we need to parse the hostname using the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/), which contains a list of all public domain name suffixes.

---

### Solution

First, include the [public suffix list js api](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wrangr/psl/master/dist/psl.min.js) in a script tag in your HTML, then in JavaScript to get the hostname you can call:

```
var parsed = psl.parse('one.two.roothost.co.uk');
console.log(parsed.domain);
```

...which will return "roothost.co.uk". To get the name from the current page, you can use `location.hostname` instead of a static string:

```
var parsed = psl.parse(location.hostname);
console.log(parsed.domain);
```

Finally, if you need to parse a domain name directly out of a full URL string, you can use the following:

```
var url = "http://one.two.roothost.co.uk/page.html";
url = url.split("/")[2]; // Get the hostname
var parsed = psl.parse(url); // Parse the domain
document.getElementById("output").textContent = parsed.domain;
```

**JSFiddle Example** (it includes the entire minified library in the jsFiddle, so scroll down!): https://jsfiddle.net/6aqdbL71/2/

Comment: wouldn't it be even more powerfull using [the a.href tip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript) as proposed by  user1551066 ?

Comment: It's worth noting that although the TLDs were fairly static for a long time, [they're currently changing](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/delegated-strings). This will muddle your problem somewhat.

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung The psl script is updated fairly regularly AFAIK. As a solution to the changing TLDs, you could have the script auto-update itself server-side from GitHub on a schedule. So for instance, every week your server runs a job that downloads the new psl script so that it's fresh for the client-side. For bonus points you could even set up a git hook instead of a scheduled job.

Comment: Well - if it does indeed update regularly - it would be simpler to simply pull the script from a CDN, instead of resorting to auto-updates and other such things. The main problem here for me is the external dependency, but I suppose if it works, it works.

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung Unfortunately I looked for a CDN for the psl script and couldn't find any. If there were a reliable CDN for the script available, it would definitely be the best solution.

Comment: This solution is insane to me. 122KB of minified code added to your library and if you dig in to the code you get very static definitions: "hgtv","hiphop","hisamitsu","hitachi","hiv","hkt","hockey","holdings","holiday","homedepot","homegoods","homes","homesense","honda".... I'm glad this solution is available but really wish subdomain fishing was built in to the browser.

Comment: Following solution of @MaximillianLaumeister, I reached [here](https://publicsuffix.org/learn/), where I could find [publicsuffixlist.js](https://github.com/gorhill/publicsuffixlist.js) and [tld.js](https://github.com/oncletom/tld.js) recommended for JavaScript, and [tldts](https://github.com/remusao/tldts) for Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the code snippet below.

```
/(?<=\.).+/.exec(location.hostname)[0]
```

Comment: It doesn't work for the example provided in the question unfortunately: `/(?<=\.).+/.exec('one.two.roothost.co.uk')[0]` returns `two.roothost.co.uk`). It wouldn't work either if the hostname doesn't include a subdomain (i.e. `/(?<=\.).+/.exec('example.com')[0]` returns `com`).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
const firstTLDs = "ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cu|cv|cw|cx|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|es|et|eu|fi|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jo|jp|kg|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|nl|no|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|yt".split('|');

const secondTLDs = "com|edu|gov|net|mil|org|nom|sch|caa|res|off|gob|int|tur|ip6|uri|urn|asn|act|nsw|qld|tas|vic|pro|biz|adm|adv|agr|arq|art|ato|bio|bmd|cim|cng|cnt|ecn|eco|emp|eng|esp|etc|eti|far|fnd|fot|fst|g12|ggf|imb|ind|inf|jor|jus|leg|lel|mat|med|mus|not|ntr|odo|ppg|psc|psi|qsl|rec|slg|srv|teo|tmp|trd|vet|zlg|web|ltd|sld|pol|fin|k12|lib|pri|aip|fie|eun|sci|prd|cci|pvt|mod|idv|rel|sex|gen|nic|abr|bas|cal|cam|emr|fvg|laz|lig|lom|mar|mol|pmn|pug|sar|sic|taa|tos|umb|vao|vda|ven|mie|北海道|和歌山|神奈川|鹿児島|ass|rep|tra|per|ngo|soc|grp|plc|its|air|and|bus|can|ddr|jfk|mad|nrw|nyc|ski|spy|tcm|ulm|usa|war|fhs|vgs|dep|eid|fet|fla|flå|gol|hof|hol|sel|vik|cri|iwi|ing|abo|fam|gok|gon|gop|gos|aid|atm|gsm|sos|elk|waw|est|aca|bar|cpa|jur|law|sec|plo|www|bir|cbg|jar|khv|msk|nov|nsk|ptz|rnd|spb|stv|tom|tsk|udm|vrn|cmw|kms|nkz|snz|pub|fhv|red|ens|nat|rns|rnu|bbs|tel|bel|kep|nhs|dni|fed|isa|nsn|gub|e12|tec|орг|обр|упр|alt|nis|jpn|mex|ath|iki|nid|gda|inc".split('|');

const knownSubdomains = "www|studio|mail|remote|blog|webmail|server|ns1|ns2|smtp|secure|vpn|m|shop|ftp|mail2|test|portal|ns|ww1|host|support|dev|web|bbs|ww42|squatter|mx|email|1|mail1|2|forum|owa|www2|gw|admin|store|mx1|cdn|api|exchange|app|gov|2tty|vps|govyty|hgfgdf|news|1rer|lkjkui";

function removeSubdomain(s) {
    const knownSubdomainsRegExp = new RegExp(`^(${knownSubdomains})\.`, 'i');
    s = s.replace(knownSubdomainsRegExp, '');

    const parts = s.split('.');

    while (parts.length > 3) {
        parts.shift();
    }

    if (parts.length === 3 && ((parts[1].length > 2 && parts[2].length > 2) || (secondTLDs.indexOf(parts[1]) === -1) && firstTLDs.indexOf(parts[2]) === -1)) {
        parts.shift();
    }

    return parts.join('.');
};
```

```js
var tests = {
  'www.sidanmor.com':             'sidanmor.com',
  'exemple.com':                  'exemple.com',
  'argos.co.uk':                  'argos.co.uk',
  'www.civilwar.museum':          'civilwar.museum',
  'www.sub.civilwar.museum':      'civilwar.museum',
  'www.xxx.sub.civilwar.museum':  'civilwar.museum',
  'www.exemple.com':              'exemple.com',
  'main.testsite.com':            'testsite.com',
  'www.ex-emple.com.ar':          'ex-emple.com.ar',
  'main.test-site.co.uk':         'test-site.co.uk',
  'en.tour.mysite.nl':            'tour.mysite.nl',
  'www.one.lv':                   'one.lv',
  'www.onfdsadfsafde.lv':         'onfdsadfsafde.lv',
  'aaa.onfdsadfsafde.aa':         'onfdsadfsafde.aa',
};

const firstTLDs = "ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cu|cv|cw|cx|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|es|et|eu|fi|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jo|jp|kg|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|nl|no|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|yt".split('|');

const secondTLDs = "com|edu|gov|net|mil|org|nom|sch|caa|res|off|gob|int|tur|ip6|uri|urn|asn|act|nsw|qld|tas|vic|pro|biz|adm|adv|agr|arq|art|ato|bio|bmd|cim|cng|cnt|ecn|eco|emp|eng|esp|etc|eti|far|fnd|fot|fst|g12|ggf|imb|ind|inf|jor|jus|leg|lel|mat|med|mus|not|ntr|odo|ppg|psc|psi|qsl|rec|slg|srv|teo|tmp|trd|vet|zlg|web|ltd|sld|pol|fin|k12|lib|pri|aip|fie|eun|sci|prd|cci|pvt|mod|idv|rel|sex|gen|nic|abr|bas|cal|cam|emr|fvg|laz|lig|lom|mar|mol|pmn|pug|sar|sic|taa|tos|umb|vao|vda|ven|mie|北海道|和歌山|神奈川|鹿児島|ass|rep|tra|per|ngo|soc|grp|plc|its|air|and|bus|can|ddr|jfk|mad|nrw|nyc|ski|spy|tcm|ulm|usa|war|fhs|vgs|dep|eid|fet|fla|flå|gol|hof|hol|sel|vik|cri|iwi|ing|abo|fam|gok|gon|gop|gos|aid|atm|gsm|sos|elk|waw|est|aca|bar|cpa|jur|law|sec|plo|www|bir|cbg|jar|khv|msk|nov|nsk|ptz|rnd|spb|stv|tom|tsk|udm|vrn|cmw|kms|nkz|snz|pub|fhv|red|ens|nat|rns|rnu|bbs|tel|bel|kep|nhs|dni|fed|isa|nsn|gub|e12|tec|орг|обр|упр|alt|nis|jpn|mex|ath|iki|nid|gda|inc".split('|');

const knownSubdomains = "www|studio|mail|remote|blog|webmail|server|ns1|ns2|smtp|secure|vpn|m|shop|ftp|mail2|test|portal|ns|ww1|host|support|dev|web|bbs|ww42|squatter|mx|email|1|mail1|2|forum|owa|www2|gw|admin|store|mx1|cdn|api|exchange|app|gov|2tty|vps|govyty|hgfgdf|news|1rer|lkjkui";

function removeSubdomain(s) {
const knownSubdomainsRegExp = new RegExp(`^(${knownSubdomains})\.`, 'i');
s = s.replace(knownSubdomainsRegExp, '');

const parts = s.split('.');

while (parts.length > 3) {
    parts.shift();
}

if (parts.length === 3 && ((parts[1].length > 2 && parts[2].length > 2) || (secondTLDs.indexOf(parts[1]) === -1) && firstTLDs.indexOf(parts[2]) === -1)) {
    parts.shift();
}

return parts.join('.');
};

for (var test in tests) {
  if (tests.hasOwnProperty(test)) {
    var t = test;
    var e = tests[test];
    var r = removeSubdomain(test);
    var s = e === r;
    if (s) {
      console.log('OK: "' + t + '" should be "' + e + '" and it is really "' + r + '"');
    } else {
      console.log('Fail: "' + t + '" should be "' + e + '" but it is NOT "' + r + '"');
    }
  }
}
```

Referance:

[psl.min.js file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wrangr/psl/master/dist/psl.min.js)

[Maximillian Laumeister Answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752963/get-domain-name-without-subdomains-using-javascript/45214334?noredirect=1#comment78046572_45214334)

[The most popular subdomains on the internet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wrangr/psl/master/dist/psl.min.js)

Comment: I'm currently trying to figure out a way to optimize your solution, since it doesn't pass the test with `www.d7143.test.me`. It spits out `d7143.test.me` instead of `test.me`.

Comment: "me" is in my firstTLDs list. If you want to get "test.me" you can remove it from the list... But I don't think it is right to do it, bercouse there are sites with "me" as firstTLD... Good luck!

Comment: yeah this is useless, www.d7143.test.me should return test.me without changes

Comment: You list is not up to date. As of today there are 1584 top level domains. https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

Comment: this script doesn't work for many cases, i.e. `removeSubdomain("main.test-site.fr")` will return `main.test-site.fr`

Comment: It is not a good idea to hard-code TLDs because new TLDs are introduced much more frequently then you think, and the rules might change too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`parse-domain`](https://github.com/peerigon/parse-domain) to do the heavy lifting for you. This package considers the `public suffix list` and returns an easy to work with object breaking up the domain.

Here is an example from their readme:

```sh
  npm install parse-domain
```

```
  import { parseDomain, ParseResultType } from 'parse-domain';

  const parseResult = parseDomain(
    // should be a string with basic latin characters only. more details in the readme
    'www.some.example.co.uk',
  );

  // check if the domain is listed in the public suffix list
  if (parseResult.type === ParseResultType.Listed) {
    const { subDomains, domain, topLevelDomains } = parseResult;

    console.log(subDomains); // ["www", "some"]
    console.log(domain); // "example"
    console.log(topLevelDomains); // ["co", "uk"]
  } else {
    // more about other parseResult types in the readme
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
function getCanonicalHost(hostname) {
  const MAX_TLD_LENGTH = 3;
  
  function isNotTLD(_) { return _.length > MAX_TLD_LENGTH; };

  hostname = hostname.split('.');
  hostname = hostname.slice(Math.max(0, hostname.findLastIndex(isNotTLD)));
  hostname = hostname.join('.');

  return hostname;
}

console.log(getCanonicalHost('mail.google.com'));
console.log(getCanonicalHost('some.google.com.ar'));
console.log(getCanonicalHost('some.another.google.com.ar'));
console.log(getCanonicalHost('foo.bar.google.com'));
console.log(getCanonicalHost('foo.bar.google.com.ar'));
console.log(getCanonicalHost('bar.google.ar'));
```

Its works since https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_domain_name say:

> TLDs can contain special as well as latin characters. A TLD's maximum length is 63 characters, although most are around 2–3.

In https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt are 1481 TLD, 466 of this has length around 2–3 and the most used TLD no has more than 3.

If you need a solution that works with all TLDS, here is a more complex aproach:

```
function getCanonicalHost(hostname) {
  return getCanonicalHost.tlds.then(function(tlds) {   
    function isNotTLD(_) { return tlds.indexOf(_) === -1; };

    hostname = hostname.toLowerCase();
    hostname = hostname.split('.');
    hostname = hostname.slice(Math.max(0, hostname.findLastIndex(isNotTLD)));
    hostname = hostname.join('.');

    return hostname; 
  });
}

getCanonicalHost.tlds = new Promise(function(res, rej) {
  const TLD_LIST_URL= 'https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt';

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.addEventListener('error', rej);
  xhr.addEventListener('load', function() { 
    const MAX_TLD_LENGTH = 63;

    var tlds = xhr.responseText.split('\n');
    tlds = tlds.map(function(_) { return _.trim().toLowerCase(); });
    tlds = tlds.filter(Boolean);
    tlds = tlds.filter(function(_) { return _.length < MAX_TLD_LENGTH; });

    res(tlds);
  });

  xhr.open('GET', TLD_LIST_URL);
  xhr.send();
})

getCanonicalHost('mail.google.com').then(console.log);
getCanonicalHost('some.google.com.ar').then(console.log);
getCanonicalHost('some.another.google.com.ar').then(console.log);
getCanonicalHost('foo.bar.google.com').then(console.log);
getCanonicalHost('foo.bar.google.com.ar').then(console.log);
getCanonicalHost('bar.google.ar').then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/) is large and probably overkill. I ended up with the following which isn't air-tight but can be extended with more TLD prefixes to meet your case:

```
const extractDomain = (value: unknown) => {
  const url = toURL(value);

  if (!url) {
    return null;
  }

  const hostnameParts = url.hostname.split('.');

  // Determine typical hostnames like "domain.com" or "domain.org"
  if (hostnameParts.length <= 2) {
    return url.hostname;
  }

  // Determine two-part TLD if second last part of the hostname matches one of the prefixes
  const prefixes = ['com', 'co', 'org', 'net', 'gov', 'edu'];
  const potentialTwoPartTLD = `${hostnameParts[hostnameParts.length - 2]}.${hostnameParts[hostnameParts.length - 1]}`;

  return prefixes.includes(hostnameParts[hostnameParts.length - 2])
    ? `${hostnameParts[hostnameParts.length - 3]}.${potentialTwoPartTLD}`
    : hostnameParts.slice(-2).join('.'); // Fallback to last two parts of hostname
};

const toURL = (value: unknown) => {
  if (value instanceof URL) {
    return value;
  }

  if (typeof value !== 'string' || !value) {
    return null;
  }

  try {
    const url = new URL(value);
    return url.hostname ? url : null;
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
};
```

And tests:

```
describe('extractDomain', () => {
  it('should handle regular domains', () => {
    expect(extractDomain('https://example.com')).toBe('example.com');
  });

  it('should handle single subdomains', () => {
    expect(extractDomain('https://sub.example.com')).toBe('example.com');
  });

  it('should handle multiple subdomains', () => {
    expect(extractDomain('https://sub1.sub2.example.com')).toBe('example.com');
    expect(extractDomain('https://deep.sub.domain.co.uk')).toBe('domain.co.uk');
    expect(extractDomain('https://a.b.c.d.e.f.g.example.net')).toBe('example.net');
  });

  it('should handle special TLDs like co.uk', () => {
    expect(extractDomain('https://domain.co.uk')).toBe('domain.co.uk');
    expect(extractDomain('https://sub.domain.co.uk')).toBe('domain.co.uk');
    expect(extractDomain('https://another.domain.com.au')).toBe('domain.com.au');
  });

  it('should handle localhost', () => {
    expect(extractDomain('http://localhost:3000')).toBe('localhost');
    expect(extractDomain('http://localhost')).toBe('localhost');
  });

  it('should handle non-HTTP/HTTPS protocols', () => {
    expect(extractDomain('ftp://files.example.com')).toBe('example.com');
    expect(extractDomain('ws://websocket.example.com')).toBe('example.com');
  });

  it('should handle non-string values', () => {
    expect(extractDomain(12345)).toBeNull();
    expect(extractDomain({})).toBeNull();
    expect(extractDomain(['https://example.com'])).toBeNull();
    expect(extractDomain(true)).toBeNull();
  });

  it('should handle URL instances', () => {
    expect(extractDomain(new URL('https://test.example.com'))).toBe('example.com');
    expect(extractDomain(new URL('https://deeply.nested.subdomain.example.org'))).toBe('example.org');
  });

  it('should handle invalid URLs gracefully', () => {
    expect(extractDomain('not-a-url')).toBeNull();
    expect(extractDomain('htt:invalid-url')).toBeNull();
    expect(extractDomain('example')).toBeNull();
    expect(extractDomain('http://')).toBeNull();
  });

  it('should handle tricky but valid URLs', () => {
    expect(extractDomain('https://example.com#hash')).toBe('example.com');
    expect(extractDomain('https://example.com/path')).toBe('example.com');
    expect(extractDomain('https://example.com/path?query=string')).toBe('example.com');
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplest solution:

```js
var domain='https://'+window.location.hostname.split('.')[window.location.hostname.split('.').length-2]+'.'+window.location.hostname.split('.')[window.location.hostname.split('.').length-1];
alert(domain);
```

Answer (score -1):

I created this function which uses [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) to parse. It cheats by assuming all hostnames will have either 4 or less parts.

```js
const getDomainWithoutSubdomain = url => {
  const urlParts = new URL(url).hostname.split('.')

  return urlParts
    .slice(0)
    .slice(-(urlParts.length === 4 ? 3 : 2))
    .join('.')
}

[
  'https://www.google.com',
  'https://www.google.co.uk',
  'https://mail.google.com',
  'https://www.bbc.co.uk/news',
  'https://github.com',
].forEach(url => {
  console.log(getDomainWithoutSubdomain(url))
})
```

Comment: domain.com.hk returns com.hk

Answer (score -3):

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dineshchitlangia/5sccn55k/1/)

My solution works with the assumption that the root hostname you are looking for is of the type "abc.xyz.pp".

`extractDomain()` returns the hostname with all the subdomains.
`getRootHostName()` splits the hostname by `.` and then based on the assumption mentioned above, it uses the `shift()` to remove each subdomain name.
Finally, whatever remains in `parts[]`, it joins them by `.` to form the root hostname.

Javascript

```
var urlInput = "http://one.two.roothost.co.uk/page.html";

function extractDomain(url) {
    var domain;
    //find & remove protocol (http, ftp, etc.) and get domain
    if (url.indexOf("://") > -1) {
        domain = url.split('/')[2];
    } else {
        domain = url.split('/')[0];
    }

    //find & remove port number
    domain = domain.split(':')[0];

    return domain;
}

function getRootHostName(url) {
    var parts = extractDomain(url).split('.');
    var partsLength = parts.length - 3;

    //parts.length-3 assuming root hostname is of type abc.xyz.pp
    for (i = 0; i < partsLength; i++) {
        parts.shift(); //remove sub-domains one by one
    }
    var rootDomain = parts.join('.');

    return rootDomain;
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = getRootHostName(urlInput);
```

HTML

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

EDIT 1: Updated the JSFiddle link. It was reflecting the incorrect code.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it actually gives the result OP is asking for. OP said that he wants to get `roothost.co.uk`, but your script returns `one.two.roothost.co.uk`.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister - I have updated the JSFiddle Link. It seems the changes did not save correctly. The code in fiddle is same as in my post above. Can you please verify now?

Comment: Your code seems to fail on `http://www.google.com/`. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/5sccn55k/2/

Answer (score -3):

What about...

```
    function getDomain(){
        if(document.domain.length){
            var parts = document.domain.replace(/^(www\.)/,"").split('.');

            //is there a subdomain? 
            while(parts.length > 2){
                //removing it from our array 
                var subdomain = parts.shift();
            }

            //getting the remaining 2 elements
            var domain = parts.join('.');

            return domain.replace(/(^\.*)|(\.*$)/g, "");
        }
        return '';
    }
```

Comment: It all depends what you consider domain or subdomain. In that case this scrip considers `google` the subdomain and `co.in` the domain :) 

Although, taking into account that domains should be able to exist without subdomains, `co.uk` is not a domain. So, in that case, yeap, this script will fail for those cases.

Answer (score -4):

My solution worked for me: Get "gocustom.com" from "shop.gocustom.com"

```
var site_domain_name = 'shop.gocustom.com';
alert(site_domain_name);
var strsArray = site_domain_name.split('.');
var strsArrayLen = strsArray.length;
alert(strsArray[eval(strsArrayLen - 2)]+'.'+strsArray[eval(strsArrayLen - 1)])
```

Answer (score -17):

You can try this in `JavaScript`:

```
alert(window.location.hostname);
```

It will return the hostname.

Comment: OP wants the root host name, your approach will give all the sub domain names as well

Comment: Yes but from the Hostname you can split it or get your root name. You can split it with dot(.) so it will return an array.

Comment: yeah but you don't know what parts are subdomain and what parts are the root domain so this is useless.