# Regex to pull last 2 segments from FQDN

Tags: regex, splunk

Working on trying to figure out some regex to pull out the last 2 segments of an FQDN.

`^.*\shostname=[\w-]+\.(?P<myfield>[^\t]+)`

This RegEx works and takes out the first segment of an FQDN.

`www.aaa.bbb.someurl.net` --> `aaa.bbb.someurl.net`

But… I only want to keep the last 2 segments of any FQDN.

I need it to be --> `someurl.net`

*Other restrictions*:
The hostname field will always be at least 3 segments - don't know the max.

This is for Splunk so I can't use a script. I need it to be PCRE compatible regex.

Here is an example of data:

```
2021-07-20 18:19:14 reason=Not allowed to browse this category event_id=12345 protocol=HTTP action=Blocked transactionsize=16051 responsesize=789 requestsize=456 urlcategory=Blocked serverip=1.2.4.5 clienttranstime=0 requestmethod=GET refererURL=None useragent=Microsoft-Delivery location=Internal ClientIP=5.6.7.8 status=403 user=John url=dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/filestreamingservice/files/abcd-efgh-ijkl/pieceshash vendor=Zscaler hostname=dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com
```

From this I data I need the field “myfield” to be: `microsoft.com`.

Comment: What if it's www.amazon.co.uk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original answer with a much simpler regex (`(?:\s|^)hostname=(?:[^\s.]+\.)*(?P<myfield>[^\s.]+\.[^\s.]+)`) that worked for OP is in the [question history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68461091/1).

---

You can use

```js
(?:\s|^)hostname=(?:[^\s.]+\.)*?(?P<myfield>[^\s.]+\.(?:(?:ac|co)\.uk|govt?\.uk|judiciary\.uk|l(?:ea|td)\.uk|m(?:e|il|od)\.uk|n(?:et|hs|ic)\.uk|orgn?\.uk|p(?:arliament|lc|olice)\.uk|(?:royal|sch)\.uk|[^\s.]+)(?!\S))
```

Or, to match the last `hostname=...` value on a line:

```js
^.*\shostname=(?:[^\s.]+\.)*?(?P<myfield>[^\s.]+\.(?:(?:ac|co)\.uk|govt?\.uk|judiciary\.uk|l(?:ea|td)\.uk|m(?:e|il|od)\.uk|n(?:et|hs|ic)\.uk|orgn?\.uk|p(?:arliament|lc|olice)\.uk|(?:royal|sch)\.uk|[^\s.]+)(?!\S))
```

See the [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eghqib/3) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eghqib/4). *Details*:

- `(?:\s|^)` - either a whitespace or start of string
- `hostname=` - a literal substring
- `(?:[^\s.]+\.)*?` - zero or more (but as few as possible) occurrences of one or more chars other than whitespace and dot and then a dot
- `(?P<myfield>[^\s.]+\.(?:(?:ac|co)\.uk|govt?\.uk|judiciary\.uk|l(?:ea|td)\.uk|m(?:e|il|od)\.uk|n(?:et|hs|ic)\.uk|orgn?\.uk|p(?:arliament|lc|olice)\.uk|(?:royal|sch)\.uk|[^\s.]+)(?!\S))` - Group "myfield": one or more chars other than whitespace and dot, then a dot, then any [second-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.uk#Second-level_domains) or any one or more chars other than whitespace and dot and then either a whitespace or end of string.

Note: the `\.(?:(?:ac|co)\.uk|govt?\.uk|judiciary\.uk|l(?:ea|td)\.uk|m(?:e|il|od)\.uk|n(?:et|hs|ic)\.uk|orgn?\.uk|p(?:arliament|lc|olice)\.uk|(?:royal|sch)\.uk` pattern part (built from a regex trie) matches this list:

```
.ac.uk
.co.uk
.gov.uk
.judiciary.uk
.ltd.uk
.me.uk
.mod.uk
.net.uk
.nhs.uk
.nic.uk
.org.uk
.parliament.uk
.plc.uk
.police.uk
.royal.uk
.sch.uk
.co.uk
.ltd.uk
.me.uk
.net.uk
.nic.uk
.org.uk
.plc.uk
.sch.uk
.govt.uk
.orgn.uk
.lea.uk
.mil.uk
```

If you want to add more second-level domain names, add more to the list and use https://www.myregextester.com or suchlike services to built the word list regex.

Comment: this is neat and all ... but doesn't account for things like www.amazon.co.uk - all you'll get back is "co.uk"

Comment: @warren It is not a requirement in the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - you should still handle it: it's a far too common use case to ignore. OP probably didn't think of it initially, but it was left as a comment on OP

Comment: also - this regex `hostname=.+\.(?<lasttwo>[\w_-]+\.[\w_-]+$)` is a 48-step match vs your 1396-step match :) (https://regex101.com/r/asdkQg/1 vs https://regex101.com/r/5gtAVP/1)

Comment: @warren You are not accounting for the fact that my regex matches anywhere in the string while you assume the `hostname` is at the end of string. This is premature optimization and inappropriate comparison of different patterns.

Comment: @warren Updated. And please do not compare pears to oranges.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - in OP's sample data, he clearly shows `hostname=...` to be at the end. And it's not a "premature optimization" - this is Splunk Regex 101 :)

Comment: I don't have any .co.Countrycode so I wasn't worried about that. The edited version is cool but is way too cluttered for me. 
The original works perfectly:
(?:\s|^)hostname=(?:[^\s.]+\.)*(?P<myfield>[^\s.]+\.[^\s.]+)

Comment: @Ben Sorry, I had to remove it due to other users' concerns. It is still available in the [question history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68461091/1).

Answer (score 1):

You could match all following non whitspace chars after `hostname=` and then use a capture group to capture the last part with a single dot.

```
^.*\shostname=(?:\S+\.)?([^\s.]+\.[^\s.]+)
```

- `^.*\shostname=`
- `(?:\S+\.)?` Optionally match a possible dot before
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s.]+\.[^\s.]+` Match 2 non dot parts with a `.` in between
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WrSqSq/1)

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to account for country codes, I've previously answered this at: [Get Domain Extension From Hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58151415/get-domain-extension-from-hostname/58153251#58153251)

The regular expression would look something like (shortened version): `\w+((\.[a-z]{2,3})(\.(uk|au))?)$`

The full expression with all country codes: `\w+((\.[a-z]{2,3})(\.(ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bl|bm|bn|bo|bq|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cu|cv|cw|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|er|es|et|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mf|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|ss|st|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|za|zm|zw))?)$`