# Mongo function to find if superstring exists in array. Nodejs,

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native

A document in my mongo 'companies' collection looks like this:

```
{
    "companyName": "",
    "companyIcon": "",
    "domains": [
        "companyDomainA.com",
        "companyDomainB.dev"
    ],
    "allowSubDomains": true
}
```

In my application the user enters his/her email address.
Using the Nodejs native mongo driver (https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native), I want to query (find) which company the user belongs to.

The problem is when the user enters the email as `name@dept.companyDomainA.com`. 
I want to be able to query and find the company document of the user based on his email (subdomained 0 or more levels), ie. **if the superstring of a string exists in an array in mongo.** 
(Caveat, I cannot store all the subdomains of the company as they are dynamic and can change at will)

Is there a regular expression way/db schema change way, to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this. First find the root domain from the email address. To do that I would split the email and fetch the domain first.

```
const email = "name@dept.companyDomainA.com";
const domain = email.split('@')[1]; // dept.companyDomainA.com
```

Now fetch the host **(companyDomainA.com)** from it. Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752963/get-domain-name-without-subdomains-using-javascript).

So, I have found the root domain which is **companyDomainA.com**. Now run the find query.

```
db.collection('documents').find({"domains": "companyDomainA.com"});
```

**I didn't test this code.**