# Get domain and path of the current url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have an url http://www.example.com/folder/file.html. I want to get domain (`example.com`) and path (`example.com/folder/`)  of the current url.

Using

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, changeInfo, tab){
    chrome.tabs.query({'active' : true, 'currentWindow': true}, function(tabs){
        let newUrl = new URL(tabs[0].url);
        currentDomain = newUrl.hostname;
});
```

leads me to getting the host - `www.example.com` instead of `example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

`www` is just like any other subdomain, so JS can't know if it's part of the domain or not. But you can remove the `www` manually:

```
currentDomain = newUrl.hostname.replace(/^www\./, "");
```

to get the path, use `pathname`:

```
const currentPath = `${currentDomain}/${newUrl.pathname}`
```

Comment: Hmm, i need the pure domain - without any subdomain, not only www. Is there a way to get only domain?

Comment: That's more complicated, as you can't know how many 'parts' there are in the domain itself. It can be example.com, and it can be example.co.uk and can be www.yt.be. You can use the solutions suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752963/get-domain-name-without-subdomains-using-javascript

Comment: `pathname` gets `/folder/index.html` - but i need only `/folder/`. Is this achievable?