# How to remove the WWW from a javascript href.split?

Tags: javascript

I'm parsing a URL in javascript to use the subdomain as a variable.

window.location.href.split("/")[2].split(".")[0];

However, **I need to remove/bypass the WWW when it's in the subdomain**, how can this be done?

Example:
http://sub.domain.com (works)
http://www.sub.domain.com (gets www instead of the "sub")

I greatly appreciate the assistance!
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282726/get-subdomain-and-load-it-to-url-with-greasemonkey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing www. before

`window.location.href.replace("www.","").split("/")[2].split(".")[0];`