# How to find subdomain in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, subdomain

I am using urls like this,

```
user1.localhost:8000//local url
user1.liveurl.com//live site url
```

user1 are not fixed , it could be user2,user3..... and so on.

I am trying to find these users name or dynamic subdomain.

I have checked `$location` in angularjs but not found any proper solution.

Should I go to split string by dot(`.`) or any other proper solution is present.

Please share you thoughts and idea on this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Tushar : is it work for usr `user1.localhost:8000//local url` ?

Comment: @Tushar : Its not working, can you please remove duplicate tag ?

Comment: Can you create live demo on jsfiddle/plunker

Comment: ok 2 minute please, I am creating.

Comment: [Here's another way using JS.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1282760/2025923) `var url = window.location.host;
var parts = url.split('.'), subdomain = parts[0];`

Comment: @Tushar : Here is link : https://jsfiddle.net/qws8cdcs/ please refer

Comment: you can use the above approach. `window.location.host` ...

Comment: can you please update it to my jsfiddle, I am unable to fix this. please.

Comment: Fiddle cannot be updated because, the URL is not the URL of the page, it's a string variable.

Comment: ok thanks for your help :(