# Is there any way to fetch only Subdomain from URL in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular6, angular8

Below is my URL and I want only subdomain i.e dnyaneshtechno

Url : https://dnyaneshtechno.sharepoint.com

As per above URL I want to fetch only 'dnyaneshtechno' I am using angular 8 for front end so
Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: What do you mean by fetch?

Comment: By 'fetch' do you mean you want to retrieve the url to use it in your code, or you want to display only the 'dyaneshtehno' part in the URL bar?

Comment: @Adam Azad I mean If I enter the above URL in any text box so I will call one function in that function I want only dnyaneshtechno from above URL . I want to get-the-subdomain-from-a-url.

Comment: @DnyaneshwarSuryawanshi, I answered your question.

Comment: checkout my answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get subdomain and load it to url with greasemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282726/get-subdomain-and-load-it-to-url-with-greasemonkey)

Comment: @ Adam Azad @ Dako patel  Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 7):

You can use split and substr functions or get `subdomain` from an url

**Example** :

**Dynamic link** :

```
let getLink =  window.location.href ; 
console.log(getLink)          // dynamic link 
var  subdomain = getLink.substr(COUNT, 1000).split(".")[0]
```

**Using Split Method** :

```
var Link = "https://SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com"
var subdomain = Link.substr(COUNT, 1000).split(".")[0]
console.log(subdomain)      //SUBDOMAIN
```

Or  **Using get subdomain form link**

```
const { hostname }  = new URL('https://SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com')
const [subdomain] = hostname.split('.')
console.log(subdomain)    //SUBDOMAIN
```

i hope i will be helpful fo all  !

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to extract the subdomain from the string, this isn't an Angular problem, but pure JavaScript. There's the `URL` constructor that can do this:

```js
const {
  hostname
} = new URL('https://dnyaneshtechno.sharepoint.com')

const [subdomain] = hostname.split('.')

console.log(subdomain)
```

Answer (score 1):

For an angular based solution by injecting the DOCUMENT from @angular/platform-browser like this

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable()
export class SampleService {

    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {
    }

    getDomainname() : string{
        return this.document.location.host.split('.')[0];
    }
}
```

getDomainName() will return the domain of current page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr and split functions, ie.

```
var a = "https://dnyaneshtechno.sharepoint.com"
var subdomain = a.substr(9, 1000).split(".")[0]
```